# Should grad students accept yelling by supervisors?

Tags: advisor, etiquette, supervision, interpersonal-issues

In my opinion, yelling and disrespecting should not be the case between supervisor(s) and their grad students regardless of how well or poor the student is doing. Supervisors are usually holding the highest academic degrees and they should be ideal principals for their students.
My question is, what to do if a supervisor repeatedly yells (whether personally or sounding as such in the emails). Do we have to accept it and do nothing to keep a nice attitude?

Comment: Can you give an example of what is being yelled (is it profane, personal insults, normal conversation at a very high volume, etc.)? And what do you mean by "sounding as such in the e-mails"?

Comment: That kind of depends on what is the alternative to accepting it, doesn’t it? In a country where supervisors yelling is part of the culture, you may not have a choice but to accept it if you don’t want to emigrate. In a place where yelling is heavily frowned upon and only done by a very small number of supervisors, you will have a lot more choice and consequently more freedom not to “accept” it.

Comment: Yelling in what context? If they are about kill or injure themselves and/or others in a lab or workshop, yelling might to be appropriate. Can you [clarify](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/176384/edit) in your question? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/176384/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Comment: Without an example, this question is impossible to answer. For instance, there could be a mismatch between the cultural norms regarding the directness of feedback.

Comment: @PeterMortensen  Well obviously the yelling/shouting is justified when someone's life is at risk. The OP clarifies: *regardless of how well or poor the student is doing*. So, we're talking about performance, grades, participation etc. *regardless of how well or poor the student is doing* In other words do we keep a *stiff upper lip* (**stoicism** "be stoic"), complain to the school authorities, demand to be treated as an equal, write an email to the supervisor politely asking them to not to shout, ask for a 1 to 1 meeting  etc.

Comment: @ Avaa Ali understanding tone and mood in emails and texts are difficult to measure. It's an old-age problem, and not everyone is able to convey criticism in such a way that it is not perceived as an insult or being "angry". I would show the email to a native speaker and hear what they say. OR... copy and post the phrase redacting personal or revealing information where necessary.

Comment: Because you use "supervisors", a plural: Is "yelling" (in whatever way the word is used) common at your institution? I also note your deadpan statement "supervisors are usually holding the highest academic degrees and they should be ideal principals for their students". That seems to indicate a degree of hierarchy and authority that many Western universities would not subscribe to. In such an authoritarian environment professors may feel entitled to show social superiority in ways that would be inappropriate in the West.

Comment: Yelling (as in raising one's voice and shouting or screaming) in an e-mail isn't possible unless the supervisor IS TYPING LIKE THIS!!! If you're the kind of person that thinks an e-mail that isn't written like that can "sound as such" then I question what else you might interpret as yelling when orally spoken in person, including how you might interpret a stern talking to.

Comment: Some of the most talented and ultimately successful scientists I've personally known have come from an occasionally-explosive environment like this. The PI challenged thought processes and decisions being made by an individual, sometimes elevating his voice, to increase the intensity of the challenge. Uncomfortable to begin with, but once a student recognized it for the *issatsu* it is, it became welcome, or at least tolerable.

Comment: … yet I’m not saying this would work with today’s students. Maybe they’ll be blessed with some other kind of magic.

Comment: That comes to my mind for this question: "A professor giving this s#### lecture just YELLED at me for spilling MY beer on MY textbook and interrupted our video chat. So ####ING UNPROFFESSIONAL. Not going to come to class in person anymore to get yelled for no reason." :)

Comment: Minor quibble: the question in the body is somewhat different than the question in the title. The question title asks if they should accept it, and the first couple of sentences at least seems to imply that you think that they shouldn't. Is there some way to edit this to be consistent (without invalidating the existing answers)?

Comment: "whether personally or sounding as such in the emails" <- Those are very different things. Please clarify whether your supervisor is doing the former or the latter. And provide more specific factual background generally.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It is not acceptable.  If this is a one-time occurrence the supervisor (or anybody else doing the yelling) should apologize.

When this happens regularly, the supervisor has an anger management problem.  You should report it to the graduate chair.

There is *usually* some way of resolving this “internally”.  In the cases I heard, the unit apologized, the supervisors were given official warning and some were eventually reprimanded (could not take students for some period) after repeated offenses.  The students were given support to find alternate supervisors if they so wanted.

Comment: Note that OP hints their supervisor many not be actually yelling, but rather using language which seems as though they are yelling, in email messages. You may want to qualify your answer for this case.

Comment: @einpoklum “ a supervisor repeatedly yells (whether personally…)” does look to me as actually yelling…

Answer (score 38):

Almost never.

An example of an exigent circumstance would be a chemistry professor yelling at grad students who are in imminent danger of harm b/c of improper lab procedure.

If these exigent events happen regularly then the supervisor graduate student relationship is not working and you need to leave.

Comment: "An example of an exigent circumstance would be..." I am not sure if this is a good reason. Chemistry labs need  calm people, especially in difficult situations. In fact, I cannot make up any good reason to yell at people, so generally agree with your answer.

Comment: @Snijderfrey: Maybe in the case of a fire, an active shooter in the vicinity, the rapid approach of a tornado, etc. But I had to really stretch to get these (and they're not supervisor-student specific anyway), so I generally agree with your comment (and by transitivity, with emory's answer).

Comment: If the supervisor notices a student - or actually, anybody - doing something that will result in immediate harm, yelling "STOP" is the *only* appropriate reaction. Of course, a closely supervised student shouldn't even get to a point where this is necessary. But if you're experimenting with sodium while talking to one student, see something go up in flames at the other end of the lab, and see another student get a bucket of water, you certainly don't want to walk over, tap the student on the shoulder, and calmly ask them what they learned in class about sodium and water.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, I get the point. Still, I am convinced that it is possible to excert the same kind of authority without yelling. Might be a personal thing. A loud 'Stop' might actually cause some people to do something unthoughtful in a frightened moment. Immediate and decisive action - yes, certainly. But with a cold mindset. Then again, I might have lost an unhealthy amount of fear of sodium, so the situation you describe does not bother me, sitting at my desk, too much.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm would the be yelling *at someone* or just yelling?  and this would presumably not be “repeatedly”, to quote the OP…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero You are correct.  Basically, the answer is no, advisers should not yell at students.  There is a 0.001% chance that the first yell was justified.  But the second and third incidents are just plain abuse and should not be tolerated.

Comment: @Snijderfrey are you likewise convinced that it's possible to do so without someone else describing what you do as yelling?

Comment: @fectin, I am convinced, yes. But I don't know if I am right. In any case, none of the two behaviors would qualify as repeated yelling in the sense of the question.

Comment: @Snijderfrey when I read the question, I have no clue what behavior is being described as "yelling." I can read that as anything from full on temper-tantrums to mild rebukes.

Answer (score 21):

There are a few definitions of yelling in colloquial American English.

Definition 1: Screaming with anger. This is never ok in a professional relationship; and if it happens regularly, it is a sign of a toxic work environment. This is not a good advisor.

Definition 2: Criticism. For example, if you do a presentation and the advisor has a lot of professional criticism, this is a good thing. The point of graduate school is to learn, and to have an advisor who wants you to improve is important. This sort of constructive "yelling" is a sign of a good advisor, uncomfortable as it is to have your flaws pointed out.

We all must use wisdom to distinguish between these two situations.

Comment: Upvoted. I (German) have often been criticized by my partner (U.S. American) for yelling at her when all I did was informing her of my opinion in a calm and clear manner ;-). Apart from a different perception of tone and a different idea of appropriate behavior there is also a different perception of criticism as such: Some cultures almost *always* view even the most fact-oriented criticism as *personal shame* and are very concerned with issues like losing or saving face.

Comment: American English speaker—I’ve honestly never heard the second meaning used. It might be regional?

Comment: @JoshuaGrossoReinstateCMs  I've seen it...but in that context it was siblings claiming they were being yelled at based on sterness and content of the parents' words rather than the actual act of raising one's voice.

Comment: @DKNguyen Exactly.

Comment: @DKNguyen Ohhh, I realize what it means now. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaGrossoReinstateCMs: I wouldn’t quite see it as a separate meaning; but they’re things that often get misunderstood as each other, so what’s called “yelling” can be either. One time I remember well from grad school: the several TA’s on a course had a meeting with the main instructor, which one of the other TA’s later described as “we got shouted at” (or some similar wording). To me, the meeting had seemed like reasonable critical feedback; the instructor spoke forcefully and with feeling, but I wouldn’t have called it shouting or yelling.  The difference can be quite subjective.

Comment: Are you sure about definition (2.) ? I'm not native to the US, but never have I ever heard the word used this way. Could that be a regional colloquialism?

Comment: @einpoklum Please read the other comments, see if this helps you.

Comment: @einpoklum Basically, it's how an overly sensitive person interprets any form of sterness, scolding, or criticism Even if done calmly.

Answer (score 16):

No, it shouldn't be accepted, unless the student has done some serious damage. But that would probably be a rare event.

Solution 1. Find a better advisor (advised)

Solution 2. Yell back (not advised)

Solution 3. Complain to a higher authority (conditionally advised)

Solution 4. If the benefits of working with this <strike>idiot</strike> advisor outweigh the pain, force yourself to ignore it. (conditionally advised)

---

Long term. Don't do that when you have an independent career. They are not a good role model.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130363/discussion-on-answer-by-buffy-should-grad-students-accept-yelling-by-supervisors).

Comment: You left out the option of having a serious talk with the advisor/supervisor about the yelling. Intentional?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other good answers...

Let's think calmly about this: in what possible circumstances should any person tolerate abusive behavior?

Ok, well, hopefully, as few as possible.

(Yes, yelling is obviously abusive, if there were any doubt. Duh.)

But, yeah, sometimes a person is stuck in a situation, and for various reasons puts up with abuse.

The point is not whether or not it's abusive to yell (in any sense), because it is. The only remaining operational issue is whether an abused person has sufficient reason to tolerate it for a while, to some better end.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be acceptable, but unless it is really extreme and continuous, **I think it's wise to live with it**. Some people have anger management problems or a tendency to yell when they are not actually that upset. That's who they are. I see no advantage to being the person who can't handle that.

You don't have to spend *that* much time with your advisor and you don't have to interact with them forever. If it's that much of a problem, seeking a different advisor is an alternative. If you confront your advisor or complain to HR or whatever, you may stop the yelling, but you will also close certain doors needlessly.

My first boss swore and yelled all the time. At first it was stressful but I decided to just live with it and respond to his requests as if they were given politely. After a year, all the yelling and swearing stopped. It turned out he had been going through a contentious divorce at the time and had been continuously at the end of his rope. We have now worked together very productively for years and I consider him one of my best friends and certainly my closest colleague. Frankly, I think he feels bad about how he was and respects me for having done good work and always been professional despite his faults. If I had gone to HR or confronted him, things would likely not have worked out as well.

Rude or loud people are a fact of life. Being the person who spends a lot of energy trying to change them is frequently not the best use of your time and social capital. This is especially true if you would like to preserve a relationship with the person in question.

Comment: Very much disagree. I would disagree even in normal circumstances (anger management can indeed be a problem, but the person who cannot manage their anger is still responsible for their actions). I disagree even more in a relationship with a power differential, where the actions of the person in power impact others even more than usual.

Comment: If you want to use your energy and social capital trying to change people, rather than trying to build your career, I'm not going to say "no." However, I don't think it's good advice to give others. You can't really change people and causing problems at work while trying to do so will not generally help you in your career or life. A supervisor who uses all caps or raises his or her voice is hardly a hill worth dying on.